# Connect only when necessary

Tags: zend-framework

I have a big application, where I use cache.

I have alot of pages where my application only connect and disconnect to the database.

Is it possible? connect only when my model really need to fetch data from the database?

I made my connection into a bootstrap. If I remove it, my model can made connection automatic?

-- edited
I made the modify into Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract::_connect()

```
$debug = getenv("APPLICATION_DEBUG");
if($debug == 1) {
    $log = "[" . date("H:i:s") . "] Initializing database connection";
    Zend_Registry::get("debug")->Log($log);
}
```

And

```
//
if($debug == 1) {
    $log = "[" . date("H:i:s") . "] Database connection initialized";
    Zend_Registry::get("debug")->Log($log);
}
```

My debug method save an file into application/tmp/logs/debug. This method show all executed queries and time. When my page are in cache, any query are executed

```
Date: Sep 10 2013 10:38:12
Access From: ::1
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36
Filename: /media/backup/www/primeseven.com.br/library/Prime/Debug.php
Access URL: http://localhost/primeseven.com.br/
Referer: http://localhost/
Request method: GET
POST params: 

===========================================
[10:38:12] Application initialized
[10:38:12] Initializing database connection
[10:38:12] Database connection initialized

===========================================
Total time: 1.339390039444
Queries: 0
```

Comment: Did you consider keeping a connection to database open between requests?

Comment: No. Did you say about persistant connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you made db connection into bootstrap? Just try to use models and Zend_Db_Table_Abstract http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html

The connection will be opened only by using the model.

Comment: yeh! at the end, I remove method from bootstrap who connect, and work propertly